# How to give parameter to view and retrieve in the view

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I saw some example with Ext (cant find it again now) that it should be possible to give parameter to the view like I do below in the push function. If this is also possible in Sencha 2, how can I retrive this value in the view ?

```
var saveResponse = account.save({
      success: function(model, operation) {
          console.log('The Account was created, response: '+model);
          loginview.push({
              xtype: 'adultmenulist',
              adult: model
          });
      },
      failure: function(model, operation) {
          ....
      }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually create a function in my custom object called something like: `updateWithRecord`. Whenever i push the object i call this method and then proceed to push it like this:

```
var record = Ext.create('MyApp.model.Adult', { firstName: 'Thomas', lastName: 'Vervik' });
this.getAdultMenuList().updateWithRecord(record);
this.getNav().push(this.getAdultMenuList());
```

Note how i use MVC ref's for both my detailpage and the NavigationView:

```
refs: {
    nav: {
        selector: 'mainnavigation',
        xtype: 'mainnavigation',
        autoCreate: true
    },
    adultMenuList: {
       selector: 'adultmenulist',
       xtype: 'adultmenulist',
       autoCreate: true
   }
}
```

And my page would look something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.AdultMenuList, {
   extend: 'Ext.Container',
   config: {
     items: [
        { xtype: 'label', name: 'firstName' }, { xtype: 'label', name: 'lastName' }
      ]
    },
    updateWithRecord: function(record) {
       this.down('label[name="firstName"]').setHtml(record.get('firstName'));
       this.down('label[name="lastName"]').setHtml(record.get('lastName'));
    }    
});
```

Comment: ahh,  cool! exactly what I wanted, 50 points to you, thanks for you help

Comment: Thanks, if you take a look at the documentation you can find that the NavigationView's push method actually returns the object. So you should be able to create and update your view in 1 line: `this.getNav().push(this.getAdultMenuList()).updateWithValues(record);` Note: never tested this.

Answer (score 0):

In your any controller, you just need to create a reference to you view :

```
refs: {
    adultMenuList:'adultmenulist'
}
```

Then, wherever you want in the controller, you can do :

```
this.getAdultMenuList().getAdult();
```

For this to work your `adultmenulist` need to add an `adult` parameter defined in its config :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.AdultMenuList, {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  config: {
    ...
    adult:null
  }    
});
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Here it looks like one retriev a value from the value? I want to give the view "a parameter" which it can load. I understand from your example that you can use 
this.getAdultMenuList().setAdult(adult) and then it will be available in the view, but one can't use the component query on a view which isn't created yet, its not created before:
loginview.push({
    xtype: 'adultmenulist',
    adult: model
});

Comment: Well then, first create the view, then update it and finally push it like Rob said OR use the initialize event on the view to update it depending on the adult value.